# How to sum up in a view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, view, addition

How to sum up in a view in swift? This function is one of the simplest things you can do, but it don‘t work. Is it really so hard to sum up two numbers? Many games have a score or something like that. How they do that - maybe you know it. I tried this (below) but there is an error in line 4.

```
struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        func sumup(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int{
            return a + b // error
        }
        Text(String(sumup(a: 3, b: 8)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

In the above code the function `sumup` is inside `body`

## Learning the basics

My personal opinion is that you learn the basics of SwiftUI, it would help you understand things better.

You could start by watching [Introduction to SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10119/)

## Corrected Code

```
struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text(String(sumup(a: 3, b: 8)))
    }
    
    func sumup(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int{
        return a + b
    }
}
```

Comment: Please watch the video in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10119/ Learning the basics will really help you.